# CLI Command to provide list of resources from subscription where user is Owner role

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Is there a way using Azure CLI to list subscriptions where I have a specific role (owner for instance).

Currently 'az account list --output table' shows all subscriptions I'm associated with.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list role assignments for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-cli#list-role-assignments-for-a-user) with the command,

```
az role assignment list --assignee {assignee}
```

By default, only role assignments for the current subscription will be displayed. To view role assignments for the current subscription and below, add the --all parameter.

You can get the expected subscription lists like this,

```
#!/bin/bash

subIds=$(az account list --query "[].id" -o tsv)
user="example@contoso.com"
for subId in $subIds
do

filteredScope=$(az role assignment list --assignee $user --all --query "[?roleDefinitionName == 'Owner'].scope" --subscription "$subId" -o tsv)

echo  ${filteredScope##*/}

done
```

I tried it on the windows subsystem for Linux.

[image]